# Python UDP socket. blind() + sendto() error

Tags: python, sockets, udp

socket.error: [Errno 49] Can't assign requested address

I'm trying to construct a dns message using udp. However, my socket connection doesn't seem to be working for UDP. I am unable to bind and send using the same socket. Is this expected behavior?

I thought this would work since I saw it here:
https://github.com/rthalley/dnspython/blob/master/dns/query.py#L213-L215

### UDP.py

```
import socket

source_address = ('127.0.0.1', 20202)
destination_address = ('8.8.8.8', 53)
data = "Hello, World!"

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_BROADCAST, 1)

s.bind(source_address)
print 'Sending UDP to {}'.format(destination_address)
s.sendto(data, destination_address)

# listen for response with s.recvfrom(16384)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`source_address = ('127.0.0.1', 20202)`

You're trying to send from your loopback device. You can't do that, it's local to your machine only. Use one of your external IP addresses, or bind your socket to the wildcard address `0.0.0.0` .